# Dropdown link doesn't appear as expected

Tags: html

[Please click this image for more info](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7opBJ.png)

Hi, I have issue on this. I have create a drop that able to open for each page for each drop down A,B and C. But the problem is I found that whenever I go to drop down A, it will appear link at browser Link A.  But when I try to go to drop down B, the page did appear but the link remain at link A. Any way to fix this?

```html
<li class="dropdown">
  <a href="Link Dropdown">Dropdown</a>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
      <li><a href="Link A">A</strong></a></li>  
      <li><a href="Link B">B</strong></a></li>
      <li><a href="Link C">C</strong></a></li>
  </ul>
</li>
```

Please correct me if I'm wrong, still newbie in this.

Comment: Add the css/js so that it behaves as in your image

Comment: Those are probably not valid hrefs. Your question makes no sense to me. You want to use CSS `:hover` pseudo-class?

Comment: Please elaborate _but the link remain at link A_

Comment: Hi, TheoritiCAL, PHPglue and @BkSantiago Santiago, actually I able to perform hover. I able to click on each dropdown, the page do appear. For example when I click at A the browser will come out with Link A, then when I go to B, the page goes to B but the link at browser remain at A instead of B. Any way to fix it? Or it is normal?

Comment: @BkSantiago  for example you guys search something at Google search, so under the search item, there will be like Item tab(not sure hot to call it) [All Images News Videos Maps More] so whenever you click at any of it the link will changed accordingly. Like when you click at Images, the link will changes to images link. But for my case, I able to click at any of those, the page appear, but let say the first tab that I click is Images, the link will continue remain at Images link even after I click at other tab.

Comment: That means you are either using `javascript` to update your content, or there is an `iframe` which targets by your `<a>`, though it most likely is the first so please include your `js` files.